# Can I recover files from a USB flash drive after running scan and fix?

Tags: usb-flash-drive

I was copying a video to my USB flash drive when my laptop shutdown. When I started it back up and plugged in. My flash drive it said problem found do you want to scan and fix. I said yes and when I open it there's nothing there. Even though it says that it's almost full nothing shows up. I've tried Recuva and that didn't help. Any other ideas? I have some important videos i need to recover.

Comment: USB is an interface, not a storage device. Was it a flash drive or a portable disk?

Comment: Flash drive. I think I got it. I used Testdisk and changed the names of the bigger files(after copying them) to .WMV and it worked.